# How can I create multiple `Future`s that can update shared data without breaking trait requirement for `spawn`?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, mutex

I am trying to create a client/server framework where multiple clients can send requests to a single server that manages access to shared data.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying:

```rust
use async_std::task;
use futures::channel::mpsc::{self, Receiver};
use futures::{SinkExt, StreamExt};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct Service {
    handlers: Vec<Receiver<bool>>,
    data: Arc<Mutex<bool>>,
}

impl Service {
    async fn handle_requests(&mut self) {
        let mut handlers = Vec::new();
        for rx in &mut self.handlers {
            let data_arc = self.data.clone();
            handlers.push(Box::pin(async move {
                let mut data = data_arc.lock().unwrap();
                if let Some(val) = rx.next().await {
                    *data = val
                }
            }));
        }
        futures::future::select_all(handlers).await;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut svc = Service {
        handlers: Vec::new(),
        data: Arc::new(Mutex::new(true)),
    };
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(8);
    svc.handlers.push(rx);
    let jh = task::spawn(async move { svc.handle_requests().await });
    task::block_on(async move {
        tx.send(false).await;
        jh.await
    });
}
```

However this results in the following error:

```
error[E0277]: `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, bool>` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:34:14
   |
34 |     let jh = task::spawn(async move { svc.handle_requests().await });
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, bool>` cannot be sent between threads safely
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this error. I understand that the future created by `handle_requests` is not satisfying the trait bounds required by `spawn` due to the fact that `MutexGuard` is not `Send`. But I'm not sure how else to implement this sort of logic. I need a collection of `Future`s, each of which can mutate `data` and I think this use-case is exactly what `Mutex` is intended for.

How can I allow my `Future`s to mutate `data` without breaking the trait requirements of `spawn`? Or is `spawn` not the right choice in this case?

---

EDIT:

I was able to get the error to go away by changing

```rust
let mut data = data_arc.lock().unwrap();
if let Some(val) = rx.next().await {
    *data = val
}
```

to

```rust
if let Some(val) = rx.next().await {
    *data_arc.lock().unwrap() = val
}
```

but I have *no idea* why that fixed the issue.

---

EDIT 2

Okay I think is the classic "holding a mutex guard across an await boundary", but it got horribly scrambled by the type checker.